# EC2 experiencing very high bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, ddos, cidr

I have reported to AWS of my very high bandwidth billing an they say it originates request to my EC2 instance.

All they can provide is an excel report on bandwidth consumption (it doesnt tell where it originates from) and ask to look at this document.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

the port that is open is HTTP and HTTPS. Thats it. not even SSH.

my web app is Django, I am using Ubuntu EC2, and nginx.

I would like to know how can STOP this attack on my server (to me its an attack).

- can I limit it to Malaysia & Singapore the request ? if so, how to do it ? using CIDR security group ?
- what ways can I stop this ? can I limit IP request to certain amount of request ?

here are latest logs that brought down the site /var/log/nginx/access.log

```
176.32.33.80 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:14:00 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xFC\x01\x00\x00\xF8\x03\x03\xD5r1P@\xC3}\xCF\x09\xE4G^m$\xEC=\x85\xA5*\xB0\xF5" 400 181 "-" "-"
141.8.144.48 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:26:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
176.32.33.80 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:26:04 +0000] "GET /vtigercrm/vtigerservice.php HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64"
93.158.161.32 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:15:53 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
93.158.161.113 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:19:15 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
116.203.1.121 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:38:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
208.80.194.32 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:29:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
93.158.161.150 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:32:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
34.230.16.115 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:47:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net"
178.154.244.168 - - [13/Feb/2019:08:38:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
```

Comment: Have you looked at AWS WAF (https://aws.amazon.com/waf/)?

Comment: The first thing you have to to do is *understand* the traffic -- you can't eliminate what you can't quantify. The spreadsheet won't really be that useful, but your web server logs should tell the *entire* story about who is doing what... things like source IP, request method, requested URL, and bytes transferred.

Comment: i get a lot of these bots. https://pastebin.com/MhZFVRfG from /var/log/nginx/access.log

Comment: site was brought down again, latest nginx /var/log/nginx/access.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common problem with the prevalence of bots.

To mitigate this in an efficient manner you can use either of two AWS services that are on offer which can effectively reduce if not completely stop this.

1. Route your traffic through an **Elastic Load Balancer** to the EC2 instance - Elastic Load balance only forwards valid TCP requests. This renders DDoS attacks ineffective since they don't reach your instance.

   It also has an application load balancer which is of special use to you since it works best with HTTP and HTTPS traffic. It synergises with AWS WAF which can be another defense.
2. **Use AWS CloudFront** - This is a personal favorite approach. Cloudfront is a CDN that distributes traffic across multiple edge locations and filters requests to ensure only valid HTTP/HTTPS reaches the instance. It offers quick connections no matter where the request originates. This makes use of ELB.

   - This also allows **GeoBlocking** which is something that you stated you wanted. THis will prevent requests from particular geographic locations from being served.
   - A useful link to a Cloudfront guide that can be followed - 
     https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamic-whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront/

Both these approaches effectively let AWS handle the bulk of connection filtering that is required.

Comment: thanks, i'ved been block IP with CIDR/32 but its proving to be ineffective and there is a limit to ACL entries. Let me explore a bit on what you said. I'll get back, no idea how it works  and configure yet. And hope its not something that is costly.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. You can check the cost with their cost calculator!
https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: i'll just award your answer first. since it looks quite good, still havent had time

Answer (score 0):

From your shared nginx log, there is so many bot service request are come to the EC2 instance. The bot service are trying to crawl your web site like "YandexBot/3.0" may use the EC2 instance bandwidth heavily.